# Application stopped logging after using ILMerge

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, ilmerge

I have a very modest application with a single external assembly (log4net.dll) that I wanted to use ILMerge on.  I merge the App.exe and the log4net.dll, and the resulting executable (New.exe) appears to work correctly.  However, New.exe is no longer logging and it was logging fine before being merged.  Bear I mind I copied App.exe.config over before testing New.exe.

I'm not sure what to make of this.  Does anybody have any idea why this would happen?  Have I mis-used ILMerge.exe some how?  Reflector seems to indicate that New.exe is "whole"; I can see the Log4net assembly and everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know the internals of log4net, but I suspect it's looking for the log4net assembly and can't find it since you merged it into new.exe. A solution to this is to provide the AssemblyResolve event in the AppDomain with a function that remaps log4net.dll to new.exe.

Comment: That was the problem, though an AssemblyResolve event wasn't necessary (I just changed the Assembly name in the Section node for Log4Net).  I'm not going to go slam my head against a wall a few times.  ;)

Comment: @codea an example of what?  This question is ancient, but I appear to have solved it using Joel's answer.  I'm guessing we eventually went back and decided not to merge the log4net.dll at all.

Comment: @peacedog Good call on not merging log4net.dll. Merging it had no bearing on what I was trying to accomplish by merging (making sure that all of our assemblies were up to date if a user takes an upgrade) so leaving out log4net.dll worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

My immediate guess would be that by changing the assembly name of the log4net assembly, you've somehow broken it's type resolution, probably for the logging configuration.

Bear in mind that your type names are now different.

This means that a type name such as

```
log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net
```

would now be

```
log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, new
```

(or somesuch)

Check your logging configuration, fully qualifying any appenders, layout patterns, etc (basically any log4net type names that appear in config) to point to your new assembly.

Additionally, if your logging config is in your web.config or app.config (as opposed to a seperate file), then the section definition will also need amending:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, 
    log4net" />
```

would become something like

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, 
    new" />
```

Answer (score 0):

trying registering log4net in GAC and see if it helps

Comment: Cannot knock you down because this would work but any time anyone mentions the GAC I feel ill. Dll Hell -> GAC Hell

Comment: from one hell to another :D. Slightly better with GAC though if u have signed assemblies

Comment: Grudgingly agreed :). Although I hate VS2010 where it knows that something is in the GAC when you add a reference to a strongly typed assembly in your lib folder so it never puts the path to the file in. When you commit your code the build on the CI server fails because the dll is not in the GAC. Aggghhh.